# How to find the best possible constructor for a Java object?

Tags: java, reflection

Given a Java class that has multiple constructors and an array of objects which can be used as parameters for any of the constructors. What is the best way to find the Constructor which parameter list has a closer match to the given values?

Below is what I have tried so far, which is basically start with the classes of the values and just try to instantiate a constructor for the case of 0, 1 or 2 constructor parameters. But I am looking for something generic for N parameters which works like how Java picks the best available method from a set of overloaded ones.

The motivation is that I have a generic `Collection<T>` with a method `add(Object... params)` which must create the "best possible" instance of `T` given the available data.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class ObjectFactory {

    /**
     * Get the constructor for a class that matches the given parameter classes.
     * @param objectClass Class&lt;? extends Object&gt;
     * @param parameterClasses Class&lt;?&gt;[]
     * @return Constructor&lt;? extends Object&gt; or <b>null</b> if there is no constructor with given parameters at the class.
     */
    public static Constructor<? extends Object> getConstructor(Class<? extends Object> objectClass, Class<?>[] parameterClasses) {
        Constructor<? extends Object> objectContructor = null;

        // Try a constructor which signature matches exactly the given classes
        objectContructor = tryConstructor(objectClass, parameterClasses);

        if (null==objectContructor && parameterClasses.length==2) {
            // Try a constructor with one parameter which class matches any of two given classes
            objectContructor = tryConstructor(objectClass, parameterClasses[0]);
            if (null==objectContructor)
                objectContructor = tryConstructor(objectClass, parameterClasses[1]);

            // Use default constructor
            if (null==objectContructor)
                objectContructor = tryConstructor(objectClass);
        }
        return objectContructor;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get a constructor using reflection, if an exception is thrown, catch it and return null
     * @return Constructor&lt;? extends Object&gt; or <b>null</b>
     */
    protected static Constructor<? extends Object> tryConstructor(Class<? extends Object> objectClass, Class<?>... parameterClasses) {
        Constructor<? extends Object> objectConstructor = null;
        try {
            if (parameterClasses==null || parameterClasses.length==0)
                objectConstructor = objectClass.getConstructor();
            else
                objectConstructor = objectClass.getConstructor(parameterClasses);
        }
        catch (SecurityException secxcpt) { }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException notfound) { }
        return objectConstructor;
    }   
}
```

Comment: [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) dedicates roughly thirty pages to type inference (see chapter 18). A large portion of it is applicable to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, well, I do not feel like implementing that thick spec. Certainly, I am looking for something very similar to what the compiler does, but picking the best match at runtime or else just calling a default constructor if there is no way to match the input data with any existing constructor.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/reflect/ConstructorUtils.html#line.320 maybe

Comment: Different approach, are you sure you need to this in such way? I think better approach would be to use abstract factory/factory pattern?

Comment: A factory should be aware of the actual types that it instantiates, shouldn't it? But in the generic collection the type T is injected. As I see it, a factory could help to separate the concerns of object instantiation and collection handling. But I will still have the same problem of picking the best constructor. Right?

Comment: You could use Abstract Factory, then first parameter would be used to return proper factory, and rest would be used to create object. For that matter Scala pattern matching is mvp, but in java you can go through parameter list, use proper setters and then return object from concrete factory. I'm just concerned about reflection that why i would propose to use something like this :)